# How to add mouse hover event to fieldset in EXTJS?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, mouseover

For the below code snippet, I want  to add a mouse hover event such that on mouse over, background color of fieldset item changes and an image is display next to the fieldset item

```
 var mainGroup = {
                           xtype: 'fieldset',
                           margin: '0 40 0 40',
                           border: true,
                           title: '<html><h3>' + displayLabel + '</h3></html>',
                           defaults: {
                           anchor: '100%',
                           padding: 3,
                           width: '80%',
                           },
                           layout:'hbox',
                           items: []
            };
```

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your fieldset configs:

```
listeners: {
    render: function () {
        this.getEl().on('mouseover', function () {
            alert('Mouse over!'); 
            //logic of whatever you want happening...
        });
    }
}
```

I would also look into `mouseenter`, if you don't want the logic to be executed every time the user moves the mouse just even slightly within the fieldset.

Comment: `mon` is redundant, the el will be cleaned up when the component is automatically.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli The use of a managed listener is overkill in this case, indeed.

Comment: Thanks Francis. Could you please help me to change the background color and show an image in fieldset on mouse over?

Comment: @user1371658 I think you need to post another question for this, after looking into it yourself first.